# How pointer adds extra value in printf?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int *const volatile p=5; 
    printf("%d",5/2 + p);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Without pointer, output is 7 and if I add pointer then the output of the answer is 13. Kindly give the step by step explanation of this program.

Comment: The behaviour of this program is undefined. `5/2 + p` is a pointer and pointers cannot be printed with `%d`. The compiler should have warned you.

Comment: You shouldn't set a pointer to an integer. Also, why are you adding a float and an integer together? `5/2` rounds down to 2, so when `p` is an actual number (aka 5), the compiler is reading `5/2` rounding to 2, and adding 5

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Certainly a warning

Comment: Unless you are on an embedded system, `int *const volatile p=5;` sets the address held by the pointer to `5`, likely at the bottom of a system-reserved memory region. Had you dereferenced the pointer to obtain a value (albeit uninitialized), you would likely SegFault.

Comment: Remember that pointer arithmetic scales by the size of the object pointed at.  When `p` points to an `int`, the size of the pointed at object (on most systems, including yours) is 4 bytes./. Hence 13.  But the whole result is undefined behaviour.  You should use `%p` to print a pointer and cast the result of the calculation to `void *` (because that's what `%p` expects) — `(void *)(5/2 + p)`.

Comment: `Without pointer, output is 7` The `printf("%d",5/2);` is giving you `7`?!

Answer (score 0):

The code is invalid. The type of `5/2 + p` is `int *`, while `%d` requires an `int`.

> Kindly give the step by step explanation of this program.

```
   5/2 + p =                     // 5/2 is equal to 2
   2 + p =                       // p has type int
   2 * sizeof(int) + (char*)p =  // p is 5
   2 * sizeof(int) + 5 =         // sizeof(int) if 4 on your platform
   2 * 4 + 5 =
   13
```